# Issue with JavaScript Tip Calculator - Result not Displaying Correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a tip calculator web application using HTML and JavaScript. The user inputs the bill amount, selects a service rating, and specifies the number of people splitting the bill. The application is designed to calculate the tip amount per person based on the given parameters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0px auto;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        body{
            background-color: #006600;
        }
        #main{
            margin-top: 50px;
            width: 300px;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px black;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }
        #header{
            background-color: #001a00;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            height: 35px;
            line-height: 35px;
            border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
        }
        #form{
            background-color: #f7f7f7;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            row-gap: 12px;
            padding: 15px;
            height: 360px;
            border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
        }
        #ocena{
            height: 40px;
        }
        input{
            height: 25px;
        }
        #button{
            background-color: #800000;
            color: white;
            width: 160px;
            margin: 10px auto;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #res{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        #res p:nth-child(1), #res p:nth-child(3){
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function obl(kwota, ocena, osob){
            if( !kwota || !ocena ) {
                alert("Proszę uzupełnić pola!");
                return;
            }
            if( osob < 1 ) osob = 1;
            document.getElementById('wynik').innerHTML = (kwota * ocena / 100 / osob).toFixed() + ' zł';
            document.getElementById('res').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="main">
        <p id="header">Kalkulator Napiwków</p>
        <div id="form">
            <p>Podaj kwotę rachunku</p>
            <div>
                <input type="number" name="kwota" id="kwota" placeholder="Kwota rachunku"><span> zł</span>
            </div>
            <p>Jak oceniasz obsługę?</p>
            <select name="ocena" id="ocena">
                <option value="" selected disabled>-- Wybierz z poniższych --</option>
                <option value="30">30% - wyróżniająca</option>
                <option value="20">20% - dobra</option>
                <option value="15">15% - średnia</option>
                <option value="10">10% - zła</option>
                <option value="5">5% - bardzo zła</option>
            </select>
            <p>Ile osób dzieli rachunek?</p>
            <input type="number" name="osob" id="osob" placeholder="Liczba osób płacących">
            <div id="button" onclick="obl(kwota.value, ocena.value, osob.value)">
                <p>OBLICZ</p>
            </div>
            <div id="res">
                <p>KWOTA NAPIWKU</p>
                <p id="wynik"></p>
                <p>każdy</p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

The issue I'm facing is that the result is not displaying correctly. The JavaScript function obl(kwota, ocena, osob) is supposed to calculate the tip per person and display it, but the result is not showing up as expected.
In the JavaScript section, the function obl(kwota, ocena, osob) should calculate the tip amount per person and display it using the innerHTML property. However, the result is not showing up, and the visibility of the result div (#res) is set to hidden initially.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is wrong, it should be:

```js
(+kwota / 100 * +ocena  / +osob).toFixed() + ' zł';
```

As in; (bill / 100 * tip / people)

---

Your previous calculation came close to 0, so by rounding you were always seeing `0` only.

```js
function obl(kwota, ocena, osob){
console.log(kwota, ocena, osob, (kwota * ocena / 100 / osob).toFixed())
      if( !kwota || !ocena ) {
          alert("Proszę uzupełnić pola!");
          return;
      }
      if( osob < 1 ) osob = 1;
      document.getElementById('wynik').innerHTML = (+kwota / 100 * +ocena  / +osob).toFixed() + ' zł';
      document.getElementById('res').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body{
    background-color: #006600;
}
#main{
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 7px black;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#header{
    background-color: #001a00;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
#form{
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 12px;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 360px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
#ocena{
    height: 40px;
}
input{
    height: 25px;
}
#button{
    background-color: #800000;
    color: white;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
#res{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#res p:nth-child(1), #res p:nth-child(3){
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
        <p id="header">Kalkulator Napiwków</p>
        <div id="form">
            <p>Podaj kwotę rachunku</p>
            <div>
                <input type="number" name="kwota" id="kwota" placeholder="Kwota rachunku"><span> zł</span>
            </div>
            <p>Jak oceniasz obsługę?</p>
            <select name="ocena" id="ocena">
                <option value="" selected disabled>-- Wybierz z poniższych --</option>
                <option value="30">30% - wyróżniająca</option>
                <option value="20">20% - dobra</option>
                <option value="15">15% - średnia</option>
                <option value="10">10% - zła</option>
                <option value="5">5% - bardzo zła</option>
            </select>
            <p>Ile osób dzieli rachunek?</p>
            <input type="number" name="osob" id="osob" placeholder="Liczba osób płacących">
            <div id="button" onclick="obl(kwota.value, ocena.value, osob.value)">
                <p>OBLICZ</p>
            </div>
            <div id="res">
                <p>KWOTA NAPIWKU</p>
                <p id="wynik"></p>
                <p>każdy</p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```